# Passar valor para uma função em java

Tags: java, android

Olá!
em Javascript para passar um valor para a função eu faço:

```
<button onclick="myFunction('valor')">Click me</button>
```

e resgato assim:

```
function myFunction(a){alert(a);}
```

e em java no android, como eu faço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Representa um botão widget. Botões podem ser pressionados ou clicados pelo usuário para executar uma ação.
Um uso típico de um botão na activity seria o seguinte

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Faça algo aqui quando clicar no botão.
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

No entanto, em vez de aplicar OnClickListener para o botão em sua activity, você pode atribuir um método para o botão no layout XML, usando o atributo `android:onClick`. Por exemplo:

```
 <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

Agora, quando um usuário clica no botão, o sistema Android chama o método da atividade `selfDestruct(View)`. Para que isso funcione, o método deve ser público e aceitar um `View` como seu único parâmetro. Por exemplo:

```
 public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     // Faça algo aqui quando clicar no botão.
 }
```

A `View` passada para o método é uma referência para o widget que foi clicado.

---

Referência aqui: [Documentação Oficial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seria melhor você colocar o que precisa pra facilitar na ajuda... mais seria algo +- assim...

```
public static int soma(int a, int b)  
{  
    int c = a + b;  
    return c;  
}
```

Comment: desde já agradeço, E como eu faço para criar o button no layout xml

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

retirado da resposta acima, é bem simples.

Comment: Não entendo o porquê desta resposta... se já está na outra resposta pra quê repetir extamente!