# Error de novato com OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Estou iniciando agora no desenvolvimento para android. Estou tentando implementa um onclicklistener em um botão e não funciona de jeito nenhum, já segui passo a passo as videos aulas daqui, do youtube, e sempre da erro na hora de compilar, o que pode ser? abaixo está meu codigo java, xml e logcat:

### Código

```java
package com.example.treino;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("wow!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### XML

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.treino.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Log

```
05-26 19:22:33.703: D/AndroidRuntime(25773): Shutting down VM
05-26 19:22:33.703: W/dalvikvm(25773): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f1dd40)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773): Process: com.example.treino, PID: 25773
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.treino/com.example.treino.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at com.example.treino.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
05-26 19:22:33.706: E/AndroidRuntime(25773):    ... 11 more
05-26 19:22:35.598: I/Process(25773): Sending signal. PID: 25773 SIG: 9
05-26 19:25:13.048: D/AndroidRuntime(26448): Shutting down VM
05-26 19:25:42.291: D/AndroidRuntime(26858): Shutting down VM
05-26 19:25:42.291: W/dalvikvm(26858): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f1dd40)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858): Process: com.example.treino, PID: 26858
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.treino/com.example.treino.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at com.example.treino.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
05-26 19:25:42.294: E/AndroidRuntime(26858):    ... 11 more
05-26 19:25:43.807: I/Process(26858): Sending signal. PID: 26858 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Você tem um NullPointerException na linha 37 da sua classe com.exampleandre.treino2.MainActivity. Se você puder postar o código da sua classe é melhor.

Comment: Ao postar a classe, não esqueça de informar qual das linhas é a 37.

Comment: Poste também seu `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Poderia ver aí na sua IDE e destacar quais são as linhas 23 e 28 da `Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado

Como o Piovezan disse era so trocar activity_main por fragment_main no metodo abaixo:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu erro de `NullPointerException` seja na linha onde tem essa declaração :
 `Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);`

Provavelmente você esqueceu de declarar um `button` no seu arquivo xml com o nome `button1`.

Nesta pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15440/8372 eu explico sobre o `button`. Caso consiga resolver o seu problema poste aqui dizendo que conseguiu.

Comment: Lucas! entao cara, o duro que o botao está la no layout xml com o msm nome(id) certinho, e msm assim ta dando erro, por isso q estou confuso..!

Comment: @AndreCSimoes mas a linha que está dando erro é esta mesmo que eu falei? Você esqueceu de dizer qual a linha 37.

Comment: Também esqueceu de postar o `res/layout/activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Blz!! atualisei meu codigo!

Comment: Você atualizou o código mas não está claro a qual arquivo se refere o XML que você postou. Meu palpite é que não é o `res/layout/activity_main.xml` e sim `fragment_main.xml`, que é o layout de _fragment_ que está vindo no _Hello World_ do Eclipse atualmente. Se for isso, você terá que mover as linhas do `onCreate()` referentes ao `Button` para o método onCreateView() da classe `PlaceholderFragment` (ou, se não quiser usar _fragments_, mover o conteúdo de `fragment_main.xml` para `activity_main.xml`).

Comment: Piovezan! é o fragment_main.xml msm, agora eu entendi o que vc disse pra fazer, mas nao sei como mover o conteudo do fragment_main.xml para o activity_main.xml, sempre acehi que os dois fossem a msm coisa.

Comment: Edite a pergunta com o codigo de seu fragment.

Comment: @AndreCSimoes _"nao sei como mover o conteudo do fragment_main.xml para o activity_main.xml"_ - Copy & paste, ué. :) O layout do fragmento é diferente do layout da activity, o primeiro pode ser incluído no segundo desde que você leve em consideração o ciclo de vida de ambos, pois em determinados momentos os dois não chegam a ficar vinculados (inclusive isso foi a causa do erro que você teve). Quando você estudar fragments vai entender. Para remover completamente o código relativo a fragments do seu Hello World, siga [essas instruções](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22482259/2241463).